# Change text for read more and comments

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have website in Polish language, that's why I want translate all of the elements.

TODO:

- Translate button Read More
- Translate "No comments" (When is 0 comments to post, is displayed "No comments" but when I have at least one, I have correct information in Polish language)

My wordpress template: Savona

I don't know where can I find elements in files to change it. I upload image with informations from Source Browser:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7MAf.png)

This is my post-content.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php

if ( have_posts() ) :

    // Loop Start
    while ( have_posts() ) :

        the_post();

?>  

    <div class="post-media">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('savona-full-thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>

    <header class="post-header">

        <?php

        $category_list = get_the_category_list( ',&nbsp;&nbsp;' );
        if ( savona_options( 'single_page_show_categories' ) === true && $category_list ) {
            echo '<div class="post-categories">' . ent2ncr($category_list) . ' </div>';
        }

        ?>

        <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <div class="post-meta clear-fix">
            <?php if ( savona_options( 'single_page_show_date' ) === true ) : ?>
            <span class="post-date"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </header>

    <div class="post-content">

        <?php

        // The Post Content
        the_content('');

        // Post Pagination
        $defaults = array(
            'before' => '<p class="single-pagination">'. esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'savona' ),
            'after' => '</p>'
        );

        wp_link_pages( $defaults );

        ?>
    </div>

    <footer class="post-footer">



        <?php if ( savona_options( 'single_page_show_author' ) === true ) : ?>
        <span class="post-author"><?php esc_html_e( 'By', 'savona' ); ?>&nbsp;<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php

        if ( savona_options( 'single_page_show_comments' ) === true && comments_open() ) {
            comments_popup_link( esc_html__( 'No Comments', 'savona' ), esc_html__( '1 Comment', 'savona' ), '% '. esc_html__( 'Comments', 'savona' ), 'post-comments');
        }

        ?>

    </footer>

<?php

    endwhile; // Loop End
endif; // have_posts()

?>

</article>
```

Comment: Do you want to change text or translate text?

Comment: That's change and translate in one :) 
I want "Read More" change for "Czytaj dalej" and "No comments" for "Brak komentarzy"

Comment: Have you used any translating plugin ?

Comment: I didn't install such a plugin myself

Comment: The best way to apply auto translation on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be a proper way, you can easily change like below.

1. 'Read More' text - Replace `'blog_page_more_text' => 'Read More',`
   with `'blog_page_more_text' => 'Czytaj dalej',` in
   'inc/customizer/customizer-defaults.php'.
2. No Comments text - Replace occurrence of `'No Comments'` with `'Brak komentarzy'` in 'templates/grid/blog-grid.php' and 'templates/single/post-content.php'.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead translating text to polish, you can change the WordPress language to "Polski".

If this is not available, please check how install a new language. You can get [here all languages](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/)

If you want only change your translated text in your current work you can do following:

**For Read More**

To replace the […] with a [Read More] link, add this to your child theme’s functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return ' <a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">[Read More]</a>'; //Change to suit your needs
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

To replace the […] with a Read More button, add this to your child theme’s functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return ' <a class="moretag btn btn-primary" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More »</a>'; //Change to suit your needs
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

If you do not have child theme, please check it.
[Source](https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/replace-read-link-button/)

**For No comments**

Again please change following into child theme:

Here’s the location of where my child theme and customization including the edited comments.php file are stored `public_html/wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/comments.php`

Once you have located and edited your comments file, save it and check your customized text.

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Put these code in `header.php` file just after body tag opening. It will `auto-translate` your current to `Polish` language or in provided language as you wish.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: "en",
      includedLanguages: "pl",      
    },'google_translate_element');
}
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ //console.log('Innnnnn');
    googleTranslateElementInit();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var a = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
        //console.log('Hellllo:: ',a);
        a.selectedIndex=1;
        a.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));       
    },4000);
});
</script>
```